# How to prove that class of “recursive” and “recursively enumerable” languages are not equal?

Tags: computability, recursive-algorithms, turing-machines

I would like to formulate a formal proof for showing that the classes of recursive and recursively enumerable languages are not equal.

I know that recursive languages are accepted by Turing machines with stop property and recursively enumerable languages are accepted by Turing machines.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to find a recursively enumerable language that is not recursive. This can be done either by exhibiting a concrete example or by means of a proof by diagonalization.

Comment: Since I know that Universal Language belongs to REL class, but not RkL, how do I formally prove that?

Comment: You have the concrete example and there is nothing more to prove.